# PHP Set Default of Select HTML element

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
<td>
    <select class="versionSelect">
       <option value="5" <?php if($item->version === "5") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>5</option>
       <option value="6" <?php if($item->version === "6") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>6</option>
       <option value="7" <?php if($item->version === "7") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>7</option>
    </select>
                    </td>
```

The resulting HTML is this:

```
 <select class="versionSelect">
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
 </select>
```

and yet when the page loads, the select element is still on 5. How is this possible?

Comment: What browser?  Seems [to work](http://jsfiddle.net/JgZ6v/) for me.  Could there be any script resetting it?

Comment: I am using Firefox 16. I mean the HTML is what it is when the page loads. I am using some jquery validation scripts as well as jquery ui for autocomplete, but nothing that changes any select properties. It reads from the select box's value, but never changes its css or markup.

Comment: Maybe disable Javascript temporarily just to see?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Thank you for the sanity check. It is indeed what Alvar said below. My broswer did not respond on refresh, only on reload. Now it works on every page load. sigh

Comment: Ah, it's always the simple things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes just refresh doesn't work, you must leave page and return, strange select behaviour in some browsers

Comment: You are indeed right. This was the problem. When I did a page reload everything went smoothly. Good looks! I'll accept when the timer has expired.